# Does ROS guarantee the msg delivery?

Tags: c++, ros

I fully understand that ROS might lost the first few messages because the publisher subscriber have not been successfully connected yet.

But is there any guarantee that all the messages send by the publisher will be successfully delivered to all subscribers (if the message queue does not overflow)?

Comment: Btw, you can also ask ROS-related questions on ROS Answers: http://answers.ros.org/questions/.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the publisher was successfully initialized before the subscriber, and the message queue does not overflow, then the guarantees of ROS messaging are essentially the same as TCP, since that is the underlying transport protocol used by the publishers and subscribers. As you tell from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol), TCP is a reliable transport mechanism, but it's still possible that your messages could get lost if the internet connection drops and the packages time out.

Comment: but if we're not using internet connection and everything is on a local computer, do you think message delivery is guaraanteed?